# Delete an entire Doubly Linked List c++

Tags: c++

I have this function that takes in two Doubly Linked list and puts them into this doubly linked list, and I am having no problem with the merging. The problem that I am having is that the two linked lists used as parameters need to be empty when it is over, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

```
void merge(DLinkedList a, DLinkedList b)
    {
        DNode* atemp = a.header;
        DNode* btemp = b.header;
        while(atemp != NULL)
        {

            insertOrderUnique(atemp->data);
            atemp = atemp->next;
        }
        while(btemp != NULL)
        {
            insertOrderUnique(btemp->data);
            btemp = btemp->next;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are passing the two inputs by value (i.e. copying them). So the function operates on the copies.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what your DLists look like, but you should not copy them. So instead of:

```
void merge(DLinkedList a, DLinkedList b)
```

write:

```
void merge(DLinkedList& a, DLinkedList& b)
```

or:

```
void merge(DLinkedList* a, DLinkedList* b)
```